# Alternative to IPicture from dotnet to delphi to include 64bit

Tags: c#, interop, delphi-xe

**Context**

I have a problem that a `dotnet dll` and `delphi dll` that used to pass an `stdole.IPicture`from the `dotnet` back to the `delph`i via `interop` needs updating and a 64 bit version as well.

In `dotnet 4.5.2` it claims that `IPicture` is deprecated and only supported by 32bit.  Th dotnet code uses `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6.Support.ImageToIPicture(img)` as stdole.IPicture;

**Question**

What is the best way to get an image as across the boundary, they actually start as `png's` in resources but need to made into `bmp's` for use in the `Delphi dll` ?

A code example would be really useful as I am not a delphi expert if you could please help.

Comment: I was wondering would a DIB be suitable?

Comment: The native Win32 raster image is the bitmap. Why not use that? You could equally pass an `IStream` with a PNG image and let Delphi deal with that.

Comment: but what if its 64bit?

Comment: So what if it is 64 bit?

Comment: Problem seems to be getting a valid Istream object out from Dotnet via the com.  It does not seem to support it that well.  I tried using Tomer Gabel (http://www.tomergabel.com) Tomers wrapper but regasm converted the Istream to IUnknown and then delphi cannot find an Istream interafce on the IUnKnown.

Comment: `IStream` is fine on 64 bit. You seem confused.